# Predicted probabilities in R ranger package

Tags: r, random-forest, r-ranger

I am trying to build a model in R with random forest classification. (By editing the code by Ned Horning) I first used `randomForest` package but then found `ranger`, which promises faster calculations.

At first, I used the code below to get predicted probabilities for each class after fitting the model with `randomForest` as:

```
predProbs <- as.data.frame(predict(randfor, imageBlock, type='prob'))
```

The type of probability here is as follows:

*We have 500 trees in the model and 250 of them says the observation is class 1, hence the probability is 250/500 = 50%*

In `ranger`, I realized that there is no `type = 'prob'` option.

I searched and tried some adjustments but couldn't get any progress. I need an object or so containing probabilities as mentioned above with `ranger` package.

Could anyone give some advice about the issue?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to train a "probabilistic classifier"-type `ranger` object:

```
library("ranger")
iris.ranger = ranger(Species ~ ., data = iris, probability = TRUE)
```

This object computes a matrix (n_samples, n_classes) when used in the `predict.ranger` function:

```
probabilities = predict(iris.ranger, data = iris)$predictions
```

Answer (score 1):

The selected answer suggests a probability forest.  In that, each tree gives a probability of the sample being in each class.  You then get an average probability over all the trees.

What the question asks is how to get probability by using votes in a ranger classification forest.  In such a forest, each tree votes yes or no for a class. By default ranger doesn't provide it, but you can get proportion of trees voting for a class (see below).

These types of models are different, and you will get different results with the same data.

To calculate proportion of votes in a prediction from a classification forest in ranger, you have to predict with `predict.all=TRUE`.  Then you get the vote of each tree.  Then you have to calculate.

```
    pred.object <- predict( model, new.data, predict.all=TRUE )
    pred <- as.data.frame( pred.object$predictions )
    # In pred, the rows are samples and columns are trees
    ntrees <- ncol( pred )
    # Proportion of trees that vote for the second class:
    pred$votes <- rowSums( pred == 2 ) / ntrees
```

Then you can add to that data frame the actual class of each sample provided for prediction, and go on to calculate overall error and errors of commission and omission.